# Grep / search for a string in a csv, then parse that line and do another grep

Tags: linux, parsing, csv, sed, grep

The title is probably not very well worded, but I currently need to script a search that finds a given string in a CSV, then parses the line that's found and do another grep with an element within that line.

Example:

```
KEY1,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-1,PACKAGENUM1-1
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-2,PACKAGENUM1-2
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-3,PACKAGENUM1-3
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-4,PACKAGENUM1-4
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-5,PACKAGENUM1-5
KEY2,TRACKINGKEY2,TRACKINGNUMBER2-1,PACKAGENUM2-1
KEY3,TRACKINGKEY3,TRACKINGNUMBER3-1,PACKAGENUM3-1
    ,TRACKINGKEY3,TRACKINGNUMBER3-2,PACKAGENUM3-2
```

What I need to do is grep the .csv file for a given key [key1 in this example] and then grab TRACKINGKEY1 so that I can grep the remaining lines. Our shipping software doesn't output the packingslip key on every line, which is why I have to first search by KEY and then by TRACKINGKEY in order to get all of the tracking numbers.

So using KEY1 initially I eventually want to output myself a nice little string like "TRACKINGNUMBER1-1;TRACKINGNUMBER1-2;TRACKINGNUMBER1-3;TRACKINGNUMBER1-4;TRACKINGNUMBER1-5"

Comment: the first number in the tracking number appears to relate to the key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v key=KEY1 -F, '$1==key{f=1} ($1!~/^ *$/)&&($1!=key){f=0} f{print $3}' file
TRACKINGNUMBER1-1
TRACKINGNUMBER1-2
TRACKINGNUMBER1-3
TRACKINGNUMBER1-4
TRACKINGNUMBER1-5
```

glennjackman helpfully points out that by using a "smarter" value for `FS` the internal logic can be simpler.

```
awk -v key=KEY1 -F' *,' '$1==key{f=1} $1 && $1!=key{f=0} f{print $3}' file
```

`-v key=KEY1` assign the value `KEY1` to the awk variable `key`

`-F' *,'` assign the value `*,` (which is a regular expression) to the awk `FS` variable (controls field splitting)

`$1==key{f=1}` if the first key of the line is equal to the value of the `key` variable (`KEY1`) then assign the value `1` to the variable `f` (find our first desired key line)

`$1 && $1!=key{f=0}` if the first field has a truth-y value (in awk a non-zero, non-empty string) and the value of the first field is not equal to the value of the `key` variable assign the value `0` to the variable `f` (find the end of our keyless lines)

`f{print $3}` if the variable `f` has a truth-y value (remember non-zero, non-empty string) then print the third field of the line

Comment: It's a bit simpler if you use `-F' *,'`, then you have `$1 && $1!=key`

Comment: @glennjackman Very good point. My initial version used that test and it took me a minute to figure out why it didn't work but I didn't think to modify `FS` to fix it.

Comment: Wow, this really proves what a total noob I am at most 'nix stuff as that looks like utter gibberish to me. :) Anyone care to explain that to me?

Comment: An improvement, assuming all lines are grouped by key: instead of `{f=0}` use `{exit}`

Comment: @glennjackman Thought about that. Wasn't sure that would necessarily be the case (though I assume it is as well) so took the safer route. But good to point out.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk '/KEY1/ {print $3}' FS=,
```

Result

```
TRACKINGNUMBER1-1
TRACKINGNUMBER1-2
TRACKINGNUMBER1-3
TRACKINGNUMBER1-4
TRACKINGNUMBER1-5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -nr '/^KEY1/, /^KEY/ { /^(KEY1| )/!d; s/.*(TRACKINGNUMBER[^,]+).*/\1/ p}' input
TRACKINGNUMBER1-1
TRACKINGNUMBER1-2
TRACKINGNUMBER1-3
TRACKINGNUMBER1-4
TRACKINGNUMBER1-5
```

Answer (score 0):

One more awk

```
awk -F, '/KEY1/,/KEY/{print $3}' file
```

or given the sample data

```
awk 'match($0,/([^,]+NUMBER1[^,]+)/,a){print a[0]}'
```

or even

```
awk -F, '$3~/NUMBER1/&&$0=$3' file
```